# Moving Transaction Data To Another Database For Reporting Purpose

Tags: sql-server, transactional-replication, reporting, archive

We got a requirement from our developer group, to do the followings:

- Frequently (every 30mins) move the transaction data out of live database to another database
- Secondary database will be utilize for Ad-Hoc query and Reporting
- They do not want to DELETE data from this secondary reporting database, if data gets deleted from the live database

Our database server is on SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Edition.

This will make sure, live data are not been queried by the end users causing blocking issue. Developer will be working on getting the Analytic data in near future, but they wanted to implement something quickly to make live data as small as possible.

What are the recommendations to achieve this?

Thank you,

HP

Comment: What version of SQL-server would you guys be using?

Comment: Also with what edition, like standard, enterprise etc?

Comment: Also, define frequently. Daily? Hourly? Every minute?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you have this requirement,

> They do not want to DELETE data from this secondary reporting database, if data gets deleted from the live database

**AlwaysON gets eliminated.**

I would suggest you to setup Transactional replication.

[image]

> Frequently (every 30mins) move the transaction data out of live database to another database

You can schedule the log reader agent frequency to 30 mins (or as per your needs).

As a side note, I will suggest you to read [this article by Kendra Little](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/09/transactional-replication-change-tracking-data-capture/). It explains T-Rep and compares it with other technologies (AlwaysON, CDC, etc).

Comment: Thank you Kin for your suggestions, I really appreciate it!

Comment: @NismoGTR05 Glad that you find it helpful. Please upvote / accept as answer if you feel that the answer has answered your question.

Comment: Only thing I am worried about is, what if we had to reinitialize the replication?

How it would be affect all the non-deleted records from the reporting database?

Comment: A reinitialize will have to generate a new snapshot and apply it to subscriber. You will be at square 1 again, so you need to be careful. What you can do is take a backup of subscriber and then after the snapshot is applied, you can do a data compare (I have used redgate's data compare and its a life saver) to insert the data back.

Comment: oh!. Is there any other way to accomplish this other than using Replication than?

Comment: @NismoGTR05 I can think of using a **soft delete** e.g. add a column called `IS_DELETED` - `default is 0 and if a row is deleted then it gets updated to 1`. Note that this requires a schema change + the queries need to take account of that new column to filter out the **soft deleted** entries. This is a big change and you need to regression test, keep into consideration the database size, etc. Another option would be to have a trigger log your deleted rows in a separate database-call it `archive database` - replicate this  db with the main one and then you create a view joining the 2 dbs.(1/2)

Comment: This way you dont have to worry when doing a snapshot of the main db. Just make sure to test out all the possibilities.